# How return a generic array of <T extends Comparable<? super T>> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm trying to figure it out why my IDE is alerting me of this:

`Incompatible types: required T[], found T[]`.

The code is in the following snippet:

```
public abstract class SearcherGenerics<T extends Comparable<? super T>> {

  private T[] array; 
  private int k; 

  SearcherGenerics(T[] array, int k) {
    this.array = array;
    this.k = k;
  }

  public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T[] getArray() {
    return array;
  }

  int getIndex() { return k; }


  abstract public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T findElement() throws IndexingError;
}
```

The CleverSearcherGenerics that extends the SearcherGenerics:

```
public class CleverSearcherGenerics<T extends Comparable<? super T>> extends SearcherGenerics<T> {

  CleverSearcherGenerics(T[] array, int k) {
    super(array, k);
  }

  @Override
  public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T findElement() throws IndexingError {
    T[] bigArray = getArray();
    int k = getIndex();

    if (k <= 0 || k > bigArray.length) {
      throw new IndexingError();
    }

    T[] smallArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(bigArray, 0, k);
    Arrays.sort(smallArray);


    for (int i = k; i < bigArray.length; i++) {
      if (bigArray[i].compareTo(smallArray[0]) > 0){
        smallArray[0] = bigArray[i];

        int j = 0;
        while ((j < k - 1) && (smallArray[j].compareTo(smallArray[j + 1]) > 0)) {
          T temp = smallArray[j];
          smallArray[j] = smallArray[j + 1];
          smallArray[j + 1] = temp;
          j++;
        }
      }
    }
    return smallArray[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new generic definition in the methods `getArray()` and `findElement()` is not needed. You have already defined `T` on the class level. Define your methods as follows:

```
public T[] getArray() {
    return array;
}

abstract public T findElement() throws IndexingError;
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that another class extends searcher generics, doing so, the problem will be translated in the other class extending it. I updated the question to give a broader view of the problem.

Comment: There will be no problem in the another class. Also in the inherited class use simply `public T findElement()`, withour re-definition of T in the method declaration.

Comment: In the other class, if I make the changes that you're suggesting, this line will be flagged T[] bigArray = getArray(); with the error Incompatible types: required T[], found T[].

Comment: What IDE are you using? I checked this in Eclipse and it shows neither errors nor even warnings. Have you really changed **all** methods in **both** classes?

Comment: Okay checked again, the point now is that the compiler won't allow me to use the compareTo method.

Comment: Thanks man for your time, I solved. I'll accept your answer so you'll get the 10 points.